# Which is broken: external enclosure or harddrive?

Tags: hardware, fsck, smartctl

I have an older *IDE* drive in an external enclosure that I connect with *USB* adapter.
During a attempt to save a System-Partiton `rsync` complains that it can not write after a while.

I saw, that all 3 of the Partitions were mounted *ro*. I checked the filesystem with `fsck.ext4` but nothing changed. Filesystem was okay.

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xeab647b8

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1            2048 314570811 314568764   150G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc2       314572800 976773119 662200320 315,8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdc5       314574848 931743743 617168896 294,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc6       931745792 976773119  45027328  21,5G 83 Linux`
```

The Device is recognized strange:

```
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 067b:2506 Prolific Technology, Inc. Kaser 8gB micro hard drive
```

The drive has 500 GB.

```
usb-devices | grep 2506 -A6
P:  Vendor=067b ProdID=2506 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Prolific Technology Inc.
S:  Product=Mass Storage Device
S:  SerialNumber=0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

`smartmontools` shows: http://pastebin.ca/3728150

What I see is that 2 sections are offline. It seems the harddrive is broken.

Comment: The `smartctl` 198 & 200 saying "*offline*" is normal.  Please include the error message from `rsync`.

Comment: Can you please describe what `rsync` operation you attempted and if the kernel log shows drive access failures? SMART looks OK, by the way.

Comment: I will do, when I no longer ill.

Comment: The Problem was rsync. It stops waiting for an event? I installt the Server new.